# how to prove the equivalent statements in matrix?

Tags: matrices

Here is the equivalent statements:
(a) A is invertible
(b) Ax=0 has only the trivial solution.
(c) The reduced row echelon form of A is I
(d) A is expressible as a product of elementary matrices.
(e) Ax=b is consistent for every n×1 matrix b
(f) Ax=b has exactly one solution for every n×1 matrix b.

And a,b,c,d has been proved by showing a→b→c→d→a,the textbook says that it will be sufficient to prove that a→f→e→a.But why it is sufficient? This proof doesn't provide the relationship between d and e. Why don't we follow the steps like:a→b→c→d→e→f→a?

Comment: If $d$ is equivalent with $a$ and $a$ with $e$ then $d$ is also equivalent with...

Comment: You can use `<br>` or two spaces to add a linebreak. See [Markdown editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first chain shows that $a,b,c,d$ are all equivalent, because it forms a cycle of implications (because it begins and ends with $a$), hence any one implies any other. So now all you need to show is that at least one of them (doesn't matter which) is equivalent to $e$ and $f$. This is because equivalency is transitive, i.e. if $x$ is equivalent to $z$ and $x$ is equivalent to $y$ then $z$ and $y$ are equivalent. Your second chain establishes that $a$ and $e$ and $f$ are equivalent, because it forms a cycle of implications with $a$ and $e$ and $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The implications give a directed graph with $X \Rightarrow Y$ yielding an arrow from $X$ to $Y$:

[image: directed graph]

From $D$ you can hop to $A$, then to $F$ and finally each $E$.

In fact for this graph you can reach any point $Y$ from any point $X$, and vice versa, thus $X \Rightarrow Y \wedge Y \Rightarrow X$  thus $X \iff Y$ for any pair $X$, $Y$.